# When a creature attacks you versus tapped and attacking rules

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I have [Hissing Miasma](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hissing%20Miasma) on the battlefield and my opponent has [Kaalia of the Vast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kaalia%20of%20the%20Vast) and attacks me and puts a [Serra Angel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Serra%20Angel) tapped and attacking me off the trigger. Does my opponent lose 1 life for the one creature that was declared an attacker (Kaalia), or does my opponent lose 2 life because tapped and attacking qualifies for "attacking" for Hissing Miasma?

Answer (score 14):

> 508.3a An ability that reads “Whenever [a creature] attacks, . . .” triggers if that creature is declared as an attacker. Similarly, “Whenever [a creature] attacks [a player or planeswalker], . . .” triggers if that creature is declared as an attacker attacking that player or planeswalker. Such abilities won’t trigger if a creature is put onto the battlefield attacking.

Hissing Miasma triggers only once.